# Phalcon: Best practice to implement "login required" functionality

Tags: php, phalcon

I am implementing a medium sized web app in PHP Phalcon with URLs that are publicly accessible and a few URLs that can only be accessed when the user is authenticated.
Django provides decorators (login_required), that redirect the user to the login page if not authenticated. What is the best way to implement a similar functionality with least amount of code repetition in Phalcon. I explored the following options:

1. Acl: This looks more like a way to implement permissions depending on user type (admin/super admin) rather than the state of the user (logged in vs not logged in)
2. Events Manager: This looks more like a way to capture signals (post login etc), but could be used for redirection by attaching the dispatch event to a plugin which checks the desired login in beforeExecuteRoute
3. Controller Inheritance: Create a controller with a beforeExecuteRoute method, and child classes inherit the property. Problem is any child class that implements its own beforeExecuteRoute, needs to explicitly call the parent function first.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I am new to Phalcon with a bit experience in Django previously.

Comment: I have always used option 3 it's simple to set up and easy to understand for anyone new to the project

Comment: 1 & 3 are both good options. 1 is technically authorization and if the user isnt authenticated then they are technically not authorized. I think this is way Phalcon demonstrates their ACL inside of a 'Security' class instead of an authorization class. Violates OOP rules but it does keep it concentrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of times I implement this functionality based on #2 and annotations on controllers/methods. I rather create an `\Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin` extension, that during `beforeExecuteRoute` is checking (with session) if visitor is authenticated at all, and (with annotations) if is authorised to access current action@controller. Offers quite an flexibility, but has a main drawback - it may run couple of times if actions are forwarding with `$dispatcher->forward()`, but its quite necessary in nonpublic CRM.

For your situation, based on my practice I think paradoxally easiest way would be to cut project into two modules: backend and frontend. Having all your public controlles accesible in frontend part, you will have your authentication-requiring controllers in backend module. This way it will be possible to create a perfomarmance-wise authentication based on any of listed options, isolating your public controllers from your problem.

Basically your question is opinion-based, also you have listed almost all possible approaches. It's just a matter of taste or ease, what will be your implementation.